# UI is not updated when changing the state of a Riverpod's Notifier despite correctly updating the `state` property

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have defined a `Notifier` like this:

```dart
@immutable
class BleVersion {
  final int? version;
  const BleVersion(this.version);
}

@riverpod
class BleInformation extends _$BleInformation {
  @override
  BleVersion build() => const BleVersion(null);

  void updateVersion(int? value) => state = BleVersion(value);
}
```

Inside a `ConsumerState` I do this to update the state:

```dart
ref.read(bleInformationProvider.notifier).updateVersion(0x9000);
```

And in another `ConsumerState` I'm watching for this state to change like this:

```dart
final testBleVersion = ref.watch(bleInformationProvider).version;
```

Both of these lines are inside their respective Widget's `build` method. The problem is, the UI doesn't get updated. Searching online, most of similar issues are related to not using the `state` property to update the object, but this is what I'm doing: I'm creating a new `BleVersion` inside the `updateVersion` method which is than assigned to `state`. Yet, the UI still shows the BLE version to be `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Note that I am wrapping the whole app in a `ProviderScope`.

EDIT: I've tested using a simple button updating the value and it works. The problem must be in the order I build the Widget tree and update the value. What I do is scanning for BLE devices, and when a user selects the device from a list, I read and update the BLE version in the Notifier, than I connect, and than I build the screen which contains the BLE version, which is `watch`ing for updates. If I instead build the screen first and then I press a button updating the UI, it works as expected. Basically, the problem seems to be in the fact that modiying the state before the Widget `watch`ing the value is built doesn't seem to work (not the way I expect it to work). But how do I got about doing it? I don't want to show the screen containing `null` values waiting for the connection. I want the screen to be shown *after* I have successfully read the values from the BLE device. I could read the value and pass them down to the Widget, but doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of using Riverpod in the first place?

Comment: @Nagual I was able to solve it after hours of trying. I've left an answer to this question with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. I'm not sure if it's how it's supposed to be done, but the docs are lacking some I'm left to guess.

The problem is that I'm trying to set the state of a Notifier using `read` *before* `watch`ing it inside a child Widget. A quick solution is to `watch` it in the parent Widget. The problem is that now the whole app is rebuilt upon updating the Notifier, even tho only the children are supposed to depend on it. But as I stated in the question, calling `watch` in the children doesn't register the first call to `read`, thus not initializing the value as needed.

My solution is this:

```dart
@immutable
class BleVersion {
  final int? version;
  const BleVersion(this.version);
}

@riverpod
class BleInformation extends _$BleInformation {
  @override
  BleVersion build({bool isInitial = false}) {
    if (isInitial) {
      return const BleVersion(null);
    } else {
      return ref.watch(bleInformationProvider(isInitial: true));
    }
  }

  void updateVersion(int? version) {
    state = BleVersion(version);
  }
}
```

My Notifier has now an additional parameter. I've discovered that using family notifiers (Notifier to which an argument is passed) basically creates a Notifier for each value assumed by the additional argument. This means that

```dart
ref.watch(bleInformationProvider(isInitial: true));
ref.watch(bleInformationProvider(isInitial: false));
```

are effectively two different Notifiers. Again, maybe I've missed, but in the docs this was not clear at all.

Now, in the parent Widget I use `watch` and `read` on the notifier with `isInitial == true`: `read` is used to update the initial value, `watch` is called in the build method just to have it register the call to `read` (like the "trick" I was talking about above).

Note that in the `build` method of `BleInformation` I return `ref.watch(bleInformationProvider(isInitial: true));` when `isInitial == false`. What I'm basically doing is: the first time I call `watch` on `bleInformationProvider(isInitial: false)`, use the current value of `bleInformationProvider(isInitial: true)`, which is updated only at the beginning of the app. But now, when I update the BLE information using `ref.read(bleInformationProvider(isInitial: false).notifier).updateVersion(0x9000)`, I'm only rebuilding the children Widgets instead of the whole app, because the parent only depends on the `bleInformationProvider(isInitial: true)`.